# Query an aggregate value as a list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a simplified version of my real and complex query that has a lot of joins.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT AVG(height) FROM users u2 WHERE u2.id IN u1.id)
FROM users u1
WHERE created > '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY state
```

The subquery is the part that doesn't work because u1.id is an aggregate value.  What I actually want to do is query all aggregate values as a list.  I can do it like this:

```
(SELECT AVG(height) FROM users u2 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u2.id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u1.id))))
```

But string parsing is inefficient, can't use indices, and it runs afoul of MySQL's group_concat_max_len default value of only 1024.

Another solution is to convert the inner query to be a mirror of the outer query, but this ends up being far too slow.  Unfortunately I can't deviate too far from this query structure because the query is built programmatically based on user selection of many filtering options.

**Edit:** Another form would be to do something like AVG(DISTINCT u1.id, height), where it takes the average height of the rows with a distinct user.id, but that's not supported either.

Comment: do you want to get list of all the avg heights of grouped by name?

Comment: Huh you have just one table and you want the avg height WHERE created > '2013-01-01'?

Comment: In the real version I'm not even querying users.  I just put this together as a simplified example.  Edited to group by state.

Comment: select avg(height) from users where created > '2013-01-01' group by state ... is this giving you your answer?

select avg(height) from users group by state having created > '2013-01-01'

Comment: What is preventing you from just using `AVG(u1.height)` instead of the subquery?

Comment: Vatev, in the real query there are many joins, so each row shows up a variable number of times.  So some users would be represented more than others and the result would be incorrect.

Comment: Rahul, it will not work for my real query.  In the real version, "state" is a column from another joined table.  I have already rewritten my query in a way very similar to what you proposed in order to verify the correct result.  But that form will not plug into the way the query is built programmatically.

Comment: Maybe you need to post the original query after all, because all suggestions are bounced back with 'That won't work because in the real query....'.

Comment: There is no original query because it can be generated a thousand different ways depending on what the user selects.  I already did rewrite it in ways similar to what's being suggested here before even posting the question.  But that won't plug into the dynamic method of building queries.

Comment: Well, it proves to be hard to answer your question based on the fake query you've provided, so I guess I'm close voting the question. Any of the generated queries might at least help us onderstand what is going on and what kind of queries you are dealing with, but apparently you are stuck with a very strict system that doesn't allow to either easily change or post your queries here. Maybe there's your problem. :)

Comment: As the title says, the question is whether there is a way to query an aggregate value as a list.  I tried to make it clear in the original post that I'm not asking for my query to be rewritten and I don't know why everyone is focussing on that.

Comment: Nonetheless, I still appreciate all the offers for help :)